# javascript extending the module pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module, decorator

First post here. Can't find anyone asking this same question so I must be going about it all wrong.

Back story:
I'm writing my first purse JS canvas based 8-bit adventure game. I wrote a proof of concept that I was very satisfied with and now I want to go back and refactor my work to be as clean, elegant, and reusable as possible. I am familiar with advanced JS and design patterns and I want to make use of them as much as much as possible.

Where I am at:
I have the following objects : Screen, Controls, Scene, Player, Sprite, and Main
all of which use the Module pattern, and are loaded through requireJS.

Now I want to make more game objects that extend the base Sprite object with different behaviours. Is it even possible to extend a Module pattern so that you can still access the underlying protype's methods?

for instance I want to add walk and talk behaviours to certain modules which would effect their underlying update and draw methods. I thought this would be elementary by calling each prototypes method through the prototypcal chain, but it's proven to be more difficult than I anticipated.

Any one have an example of a Decorator or Composition pattern that can be applied to the Module pattern and create objects with different behaviours?

If not possible, how might I go about this?
Should I scrap the Module Pattern altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible:

```
define('mod1', function() {
   ...
});

define('mod2', ['mod1'] function(Mod1) {
   Mod1.prototype.newFunction = function() {
   ...
   };
});
```